NG - Problem navigating back to Login-Page after successful Logout
I have the problem with my angular spa, that after the user successfully logs out, the navigation back to the login page per default doesn´t work. This means https://domain.tld/login is shown in the URL-Field of the Browser, but the router-outlet is empty. After a page reload the wanted login-page is shown.
Here´s my routing
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: LoginComponent,
    data: {
      reuse: false
    }
  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent,
    data: {
      reuse: false
    }
  }
]

This is my Auth-Service with the Logout-Method
export class AuthService {
    private currentUserSubject: BehaviorSubject<LoginStatus>;
    public currentUser$: Observable<LoginStatus>;

    constructor(private readonly http: HttpClient, private readonly router: Router) {
        this.currentUserSubject = new BehaviorSubject<LoginStatus>(
            JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'))
        );
        this.currentUser$ = this.currentUserSubject.asObservable();
    }

    public get currentUserValue(): LoginStatus {
        return this.currentUserSubject.value;
    }

    login(loginUser: LoginUserDto): Observable<LoginStatus> {
        return this.http.post<LoginStatus>(`${environment.serviceHost}/login`, loginUser, httpOptions)
            .pipe(map(loginStatus => {
                localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(loginStatus));
                this.currentUserSubject.next(loginStatus);
                return loginStatus;
            }));
    }

    unassignCurrentUser(): void {
        localStorage.removeItem('currentUser');
        this.currentUserSubject.next(null);
    }

    logout(): void {
        this.unassignCurrentUser();
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    }
}


Additional Info: This may be caused by fullcalendar plugin, because when I login I always get this error: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node...at OffscreenFragmentComponent.ngOnDestroy (fullcalendar-angular.mjs:111:30).
When I reload the page with cleaning caches the error disappears, and a logout after that navigates to default login page successfully.
Edit: I added the following stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-j5yt7d?file=package.json to clearify the connection to fullcalendar. In this stackblitz you can login with any credentials (for testing purposes). A login leads to a first page with the fullcalendar in use, when you want to logout directly via that page, it does not navigate to login screen again. It just navigates back to the login page if you do an intermediate reload when logged in. This error message is shown: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node...at OffscreenFragmentComponent.ngOnDestroy (fullcalendar-angular.mjs:111:30)

change code in your routing module, for empty path like this:
{
   path: '',
   pathMatch: 'full',
   redirectTo: 'login',
},

also try this.router.navigateByUrl('/login') in logout function.

Thx @kian, but unfortunately this has no effect on the problem that the logout-navigation does not work

Now I found a solution for this, the reason that used to crash fullcalendar and caused the other problem, was a duplicate use of router-outlet in my main template:
app.component.html
<mat-sidenav-container *ngIf="!!currentUser" autosize>
  <mat-sidenav #sidenav fixedInViewport="false" mode="side" opened>
    <section [class.sidenav]="false">
      <mat-list class="nav" *ngFor="let route of routeLinks">
        <mat-list-item
          routerLinkActive="active-link"
          class="hover"
          routerLink="{{ route.link }}"
        >
          <mat-icon mat-list-icon matTooltipPosition="right">
            {{ route.icon }}</mat-icon
          >
        </mat-list-item>
      </mat-list>
    </section>
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content>
    <div class="content-container">
      // here
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>

<mat-sidenav-container *ngIf="!currentUser" autosize>
  <div class="content-container">
    // here
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
</mat-sidenav-container>

the new app.component.html:
<mat-sidenav-container autosize>
  <mat-sidenav *ngIf="!!currentUser" #sidenav fixedInViewport="false" mode="side" opened>
    <section [class.sidenav]="false">
      <mat-list class="nav" *ngFor="let route of routeLinks">
        <mat-list-item
          routerLinkActive="active-link"
          class="hover"
          routerLink="{{ route.link }}"
        >
          <mat-icon mat-list-icon matTooltipPosition="right">
            {{ route.icon }}</mat-icon
          >
        </mat-list-item>
      </mat-list>
    </section>
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content>
    <div class="content-container">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>

As you can see in the upper code, displaying router-outlet depends on currentUser, this value changes through login from null|undefined to a valid User. While this changes it destroys and inits the router-outlet...
